# Select all records from A and the respective amount of related records from B in MySQL

Tags: mysql

This is the first time I actually work with MySQL ...

**I got the following situation:**

I got the tables A and B.
A has a 1:n relation to B.
(B has a foreign key column pointing to A).

**The result I need:**

All records in A plus the count of all records in B related the respective
record in A.

Example:

[image: Example]

**What I did so far:**

I created the following query:

```
SELECT A.*, COUNT(*) AS B_count
    FROM $db.A AS A JOIN $db.B AS B ON (A.id=B.A_id)
    GROUP BY A.id
```

**My problem:**

The query I created only returns records from A that have records in B related to them (the ON statement)

**Question:**

What do I need to do in order to also obtain all records from A that have 0 records in B related to them?

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE `LEFT JOIN` and Count the `B.id`, if you dont get match you will have null and count will return 0

```
SELECT A.*, COUNT(B.id)
FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN  TableB B
  ON A.id = B.id
```

Comment: Accepted answer because this also solved the problem of having B_count = 1 for record 4 in A

Answer (score 1):

to get rows with 0 counts you have to use LEFT join, like:

```
SELECT A.*, COUNT(B.id) AS B_count
FROM $db.A AS A LEFT JOIN $db.B AS B ON (A.id=B.A_id)
GROUP BY A.id
```

Comment: Thank you. The count(*) caused the problem that I got a B_count of 1 instead of 0 for record 4 in table A. After fixing this it now works as expected.

Comment: @Benjamin nope, you've misunderstood answer and problem

Comment: Ok so i figure that * represents all columns (also those of A which are not empty) so it is counted as one?

Comment: @Benjamin what I want to say is that LEFT join was the root of the problem, count is another one, but you're right that * represents all columns, so for empty B row it will still return 1